# Group by isnt calculating quantity and price?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to export sales report from table 'sales'

It has field names `pname, price, sold_to, pquantity, pamount, date`

Here I don't wish to display the same company I sold_to over and over if the company purchased same product on 2021-02-13 so I tried to group by the *query* but then **it isn't showing total sum of `pquantity` and `pamount` in results even though it groups same company**.

could someone help me out with fixing the query?

Here is my MYSQL query:

```
    SELECT * FROM sales 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
    GROUP BY pname, sold_to, pquantity, pamount, date 
    ORDER BY sale_id DESC
```

I am definitely doing it wrong would appreciate if someone could help me correct the logic.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries - and note that functions cannot use indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUM()` to get sum of quantity and amount

```
SELECT pname, sold_to, date, SUM(pquantity), SUM(pamount) 
FROM sales 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
GROUP BY pname, sold_to, date 
ORDER BY sale_id DESC
```